# Understanding the logical context

Tags: z3

When I display my logical context after having checked it, I get, among many other things:

```
inconsistent():1
m_asserted_formulas.inconsistent():1
#1 := true
#2 := false
... (follows around 40 of theses assertions)
#144 := (not #143)
asserted formulas:
#23 #125 .... #2
```

I understand that in the list of asserted formulas, there are some inconsistencies. The first one I see is assertion number 2:

```
#2 := false
```

Am I right, or could it be that "false" is a true assertion ?

Thanks in advance,

AG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `false` was asserted to be true in your context. Note that, the context is tagged as inconsistent: `inconsistent():1`. The `1` here means `true` as usual in C. Note that, this low level representation of the logical context should only be used for debugging purposes. It is not really meant for "external" consumption. Finally, `false` may have not been explicitly asserted by the user, but is instead implied by the assertions performed by the user.

Comment: I see. Something like 2=1 could have been asserted, which is equivalent to asserting false. I am glad I asked the question. Thanks for the answer. I am indeed debugging.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. `assert 2=1` is equivalent to `assert false`.